# Can't find login page for cable modem

Tags: cable, password-protection, cable-modem

I want to double check that the password of my cable modem is not the default. I have an ARRIS TM1602. If I go to 192.168.100.1, this appears to be the cable modem management URL. There is no option to login or change a password.

Has Optimum disabled this feature?

Is there a specific URL I should try?

Comment: Is this your modem? Or, does it belong to the ISP (and then you cannot manage it). Default LAN address may be 192.168.1.1 .  If owned by the ISP,  they can tell you what they set the default LAN address to be

Comment: I bought it from Arris. It does say Optimum on the front though. My guess is that they locked it down to only work with Optimum @John

Comment: I had an Arris once (ISP changed it to a Hitron). The Arris has a WAN (Cable port) and a LAN (wireless and 4 wired ports) (assuming similar to what I had).  The Documentation should give you the modem and LAN management addresses and default passwords).  My unit was in bridged mode and I never had to access it, but the LAN address was 192.168.1.1 while the technician was setting it up